# How to run inference from a frozen-graph (efficentdet-dX.pb) file in tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: object-detection, tf.keras, automl, tensorflow2.x

I have trained an `efficentdet-d4` model using the [automl pipeline](https://github.com/google/automl/tree/master/efficientdet) which has generated `.ckpt` files, which I have converted to a `.pb` (frozen-graph) file using the command given in the `automl` repository.

```
python ./tensorflow/automl/efficientdet/model_inspect.py --runmode=saved_model --model_name=efficientdet-d4 --ckpt_path= ./models/model_d4_1/ --saved_model_dir=./frozen_graph/model_d4_1_80/ --hparams=./models/model_d4_1/config.yaml
```

Now, I wants to run this `frozen-graph (efficentdet-d4.pb)` file on a given image. For that, I have followed the tensorflow [object-detection-api docs](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_object_detection_saved_model.html#load-the-model) and [official Guides](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/inference_from_saved_model_tf2_colab.ipynb) to run the model and make inferences but it throws me `'AutoTrackable' object is not callable` error.
**Please Note :** This same code runs fine if I use a pre-trained network given in the [TF2 Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md).

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL = "../frozen_graph/model_d4_1_80/"
detect_fn = tf.saved_model.load(PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL)

IMAGE_PATHS = ['../model_input/d4_input.jpg']
for path in IMAGE_PATHS:
    image = np.array(Image.open(path))
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_np)
    input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    print(detections)
```

I have tried to debug in how automl create the frozen-graph, here are some of the key paths that may be helpful:
[export_saved_model](https://github.com/google/automl/blob/master/efficientdet/model_inspect.py#L140) > [build](https://github.com/google/automl/blob/master/efficientdet/inference.py#L439) & [export](https://github.com/google/automl/blob/master/efficientdet/inference.py#L583)

Comment: Please Note: I was able to make inference for a single image using the terminal command given in automl. This command run the inference, draw the inference on the image and saves the image in given directory. But What I wanted is to access the detections in the python code rather then drawing them on the image, moreover integrating the complete automl repository code just for running inference doesn't seems like the right approach.

Comment: Command I used :  
python ./tensorflow/automl/efficientdet/model_inspect.py --runmode=saved_model_infer --model_name=efficientdet-d4 --saved_model_dir=./frozen_graph/model_d4_1_80/efficientdet-d4_frozen.pb --input_image=./model_input/d4_input.jpg --output_image_dir=./model_input/